# How compatible are static class methods and regular routine pointers?

Tags: delphi, function-pointers, delphi-2007, static-methods

It seems to me that static class methods and regular routine pointers are compatible from a practical viewpoint but the compiler doesn't know this. Example:

```
type
  TFunc = function(i: Integer): string;

  TMyClass = class
  public
    class function StaticMethod(i: Integer): string; static;
  end;

class function TMyClass.StaticMethod(i: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := '>' + IntToStr(i) + '<';
end;

function GlobalFunc(i: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := '{' + IntToStr(i) + '}';
end;

procedure CallIt(func: TFunc);
begin
  Writeln(func(42));
end;

begin
  CallIt(TMyClass.StaticMethod); //       1a: doesn't compile
  CallIt(GlobalFunc); //                  1b: compiles

  CallIt(@TMyClass.StaticMethod); //      2a: compiles iff $TYPEDADDRESS OFF
  CallIt(@GlobalFunc); //                 2b: compiles iff $TYPEDADDRESS OFF

  CallIt(Addr(TMyClass.StaticMethod)); // 3a: compiles
  CallIt(Addr(GlobalFunc)); //            3b: compiles

  Readln;
end.
```

As noted in the comments, 3a and 3b both compile (where *compiles* includes *works at runtime in this simple example*). 2a and 2b both compile if and only if `$TYPEDADDRESS` is `OFF`. But 1a/1b are different: 1b always compiles while 1a never compiles. Is this distinction by design? Is using 3a save or have I overlooked any pitfalls?

Comment: `CallIt(@TMyClass.StaticMethod);` works fine for me.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I use `$TYPEDADDRESS ON`.

Comment: @Ulrich - Serg already gave the answer that `Addr()` is immune to {$T+} and `@` is not. This is [documented](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Addr.html).

Comment: @Sertac, I know. I just wanted to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference on binary level between static class function and ordinary function with the same arguments&result type - they are *binary* compatible, so your example is OK. Of course they are different types for the compiler, so you need `Addr()` or `@` to compile your example.

`Addr()` is equivalent to the `@` operator except that it is unaffected by the $T compiler directive.If you switch type check on your example will not compile:

```
{$T+}
begin
  CallIt(@TMyClass.StaticMethod);
  Readln;
end.
```

[Pascal Error] Project10.dpr(28): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TFunc' and 'Pointer'

Comment: Re *different types for the compiler*: That's the point - why aren't they at least assignment compatible? AFAIR in C++ global routines and static methods are interchangeable were applicable.

Comment: @Ulrich - That is a compiler designer choice. I suppose the compiler designers remove traditional pascal "strong typing" restriction only then it is really necessary to add new functionality to the language (ex for generics).