# Type of a static class method in D2007

Tags: delphi, function-pointers, static-methods, delphi-2007

In XE6 the following compiles:

```
type
  TMyProc = procedure(AInt: Integer);

  TMyClass = class
    class procedure Proc(AInt: Integer); static;
  end;

procedure Test;
var
  proc: TMyProc;
begin
  proc := TMyClass.Proc; // error here in D2007
end;
```

In D2007 this gives an error E2009 about incompatible types. I know that in D2007 static class methods and global routines [aren't assignment-compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940171/how-compatible-are-static-class-methods-and-regular-routine-pointers) but is there a different way to define TMyProc so that the above compiles in D2007?

Comment: Why not put an `@` before `TMyClass.Proc` and turn `$TYPEDADDRESS ` off for that snippet or use `Addr`?

Comment: That's my current workaround. I use `Addr(proc)` with some `{$IF CompilerVersion...}`. So I get type safety in XE6 while it still compiles in D2007. But that looks really ugly. If I could specify a type I'd centralize the ugliness using overloading.

Comment: You can't. It was a compiler bug. Deal with it ;)

Comment: I'm afraid so. :)